# Extracting all comments from Yahoo Finance community Forum

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on scraping comments and their replies from the Yahoo Finance conversation page for specific stocks (like [TSLA](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/community)) using Python Selenium. Extracting all comments along with their replies is challenging because Yahoo Finance requires user interaction to display replies under each comment, and individual comments lack unique identifiers. Additionally, handling deleted comments adds to the complexity.

Here's the method I've employed so far.

```
import requests
import json

# Prepare the payload for the API request using the updated 'spotId' and 'uuid'
api_url = "https://api-2-0.spot.im/v1.0.0/conversation/read"
payload = json.dumps({
  "conversation_id": "sp_Rba9aFpG_finmb$27444752",  # Updated to match the desired format
  "count": 250,
  "offset": 0,
  "sort_by": "newest"  # Assuming you want to sort by the newest; adjust as needed
})

api_headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'x-spot-id': "sp_Rba9aFpG",  # Spot ID as per your configuration
  'x-post-id': "finmb$27444752",  # Post ID updated to reflect the desired conversation
  # Include any other necessary headers as per the API documentation or your requirements
}

# Make the API request to fetch the conversation data
response = requests.post(api_url, headers=api_headers, data=payload)

# Parse the JSON response and print it
data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))  # Print the response data formatted for readability
```

Comment: Umm... where does selenium come to play here? You are using HTTP requests and API Endpoints. What problems are you facing with this method?

Comment: I ran your code, it is fetching comments and their replies as well. I don't understand what issue you are facing.

Comment: So the issue here is i want all the comments "all of them " to be extracted.
Through my code only one thread of conversation is been extracted.

Comment: Do you also want the replies?

Comment: yes collecting all of the comments and their replies is my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep hiting the API in loop until all comments are exhausted.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
import json

# Prepare the payload for the API request using the updated 'spotId' and 'uuid'
api_url = "https://api-2-0.spot.im/v1.0.0/conversation/read"
payload = {
    "conversation_id": "sp_Rba9aFpG_finmb$27444752",
    "count": 25,
    "offset": 0,
    "sort_by": "newest",
}


api_headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "x-spot-id": "sp_Rba9aFpG",  # Spot ID as per your configuration
    "x-post-id": "finmb$27444752",  # Post ID updated to reflect the desired conversation
    # Include any other necessary headers as per the API documentation or your requirements
}

# Make the API request to fetch the conversation data
response = requests.post(api_url, headers=api_headers, data=json.dumps(payload))


comments = []
data = response.json()
while data["conversation"]["has_next"]:
    comm = data["conversation"]["comments"]
    comments.extend(comm)
    pprint(comm)

    payload["offset"] = data["conversation"]["offset"]
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=api_headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    data = response.json()
    


pprint(comments)
```

That's the code but for something like this which has around 900k comments, it is almost impossible to get there without any errors.

So I would recommend you keep committing these comments to a database like `SQLITE`, and create `checkpoints` (containing the last `offset`), so in case of any failure, it will be possible to start from where it left off.

There is also the concern that Yahoo will ban you from the API.